# How to add UITabBarController to OpenGL xCode 4.2 template?

Tags: objective-c, uikit, ios5, opengl-es-2.0

How to add UITabBarController to OpenGL xCode 4.2 template ? For some reasons, I have to mix UIKit project with OpenGL ES template.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the OpenGL ES template to use OpenGL in a project. Just use the tab bar template for your project and then copy the necessary files over from the OpenGL project.

You just need to set up the OpenGL view controller as one of the tab bar controller's view controllers.

If you want to be able to tab between multiple view OpenGL views, you'll need to set up multiple OpenGL views controllers, one for each tab.